# Already created UIViews with tags becomes NULL

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, tags

I have a `UIButton` and on clicking it, the following block is executed. This block creates a `UITextView` and adds it as a subview to a new `UIView` with a **tag**. On clicking the `UIButton` multiple times, this code block executes and outputs multiple UIViews one below the other.

```
int commentCount=1;
y=0;


- (IBAction)OnClickAddAnother:(id)sender
{
     UIView *_extraCommentView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,y,280,198)];
     _extraCommentView.tag=commentCount;

     UITextView *commentTextView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 29, 280, 134)];
     commentTextView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(195.0/255.0) green:(195.0/255.0) blue:(195.0/255.0) alpha:1];

     [_extraCommentView addSubview:commentTextView];


     UIView *previous=(UIView *)[_extraCommentView viewWithTag:1];
     UIView *next=(UIView *)[_extraCommentView viewWithTag:2];
     NSLog(@"prev  ->%@",previous);
     NSLog(@"nxt   ->%@",next);

     commentCount++;
     y+=200
}
```

I tried to access `UIViews` with tags '1' and '2'. For example, when i click the `UIButton` 4 times, this block executes 4 times and i get this log:

```
2014-04-03 16:24:15.106 SmartWatch[2465:70b] pre1-><UIView: 0x8c69440; frame = (0 -396; 280 198); tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c6b5e0>>
2014-04-03 16:24:15.107 SmartWatch[2465:70b] nxt1->(null)

2014-04-03 16:24:16.450 SmartWatch[2465:70b] pre1->(null)
2014-04-03 16:24:16.450 SmartWatch[2465:70b] nxt1-><UIView: 0x8c4f2f0; frame = (0 -198; 280 198); tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c55ca0>>

2014-04-03 16:24:16.642 SmartWatch[2465:70b] pre1->(null)
2014-04-03 16:24:16.642 SmartWatch[2465:70b] nxt1->(null)

2014-04-03 16:24:16.945 SmartWatch[2465:70b] pre1->(null)
2014-04-03 16:24:16.946 SmartWatch[2465:70b] nxt1->(null)
```

why does `UIViews` with tag '1' and '2' return NULL for 3rd and 4th clicks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine in first iteration you create:

```
_extraCommentView with tag = 1 
commentTextView no tag
```

and the result is

```
tag 1 - _extraCommentView which is right
tag 2 is NULL which is also right.
```

In the second iteration you create

```
_extraCommentView with tag = 2
commentTextView no tag
```

and the result is:

```
tag 1 null 
tag 2 _extraCommentView
```

which is also right.

In the 3th iteration you create

```
  _extraCommentView with tag = 3
  commentTextView` no tag
```

and the result is:

```
tag 1 null 
tag 2 null
```

So answer for your question:

> why does UIViews with tag '1' and '2' return NULL for 3rd and 4th
>   clicks?

in 3th and 4th button click the commentCount is equal 3 and for but the NSLogs log views just for tag 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

@Greg answer is right, if you want a list of views try adding to an array

```
 NSMutableArray *viewArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
- (IBAction) OnClickAddAnother:(id)sender 
{

     UIView *_extraCommentView=[[[UIView alloc]init ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,y,280,198)];
    _extraCommentView.tag=commentCount;

    UITextView *commentTextView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 29, 280, 134)];
    commentTextView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(195.0/255.0) green:(195.0/255.0) blue:(195.0/255.0) alpha:1];

    [_extraCommentView addSubview:commentTextView];

    [viewArray addObject:_extraCommentView];
    for(UIView *view in viewArray )
    {
        NSLog(@"View  ->%@",view);
    }

    commentCount++;
    y+=200;
}
```